# Sort an array with multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I am trying to sort alphabetically by dogName, however the standard *array*.sort doesn't work. I even tried (*array*.dogName).sort() to no avail. What do I need to do?

```
var garrDog = [];

function start() {
    var vName = '';
    var vToys = '';
    vName = prompt("Enter the dog's name (leave blank to stop):");
    while (vName.length > 0) {
        var valueToPush = {};
         vToys = prompt("Enter number of toys " + vName + " has:");
         valueToPush['dogName'] = vName;
         valueToPush['dogToys'] = vToys;
         garrDog.push(valueToPush);
         vName = prompt("Enter the dog's name (leave blank to stop)");
     }
     listDogs();
 }

function listDogs() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < garrDog.length) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += ('Dog ' + (i+1) + ' Name: ' + garrDog[i].dogName + ' No. of toys: ' + garrDog[i].dogToys + '<br />');
        i++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: MDN's doco page for the [standard array `.sort()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control) has an example of how to sort an array of objects.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thank you so much. Worked like a charm